# Indexing certain values in a function

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame that looks like this:

```
 df <- 
 ID      TIME     AMT     k10     k12     k21
1.00    0.00    50.00   0.10    0.40    0.01
1.00    1.00    0.00    0.10    0.40    0.01
1.00    2.00    0.00    0.10    0.40    0.01
1.00    3.00    50.00   0.10    0.40    0.01
1.00    4.00    0.00    0.10    0.40    0.01
2.00    0.00    100.00  0.25    0.50    0.06
2.00    1.00    0.00    0.25    0.50    0.06
2.00    2.00    0.00    0.25    0.50    0.06
```

I am using the values of `k10, k12, k21` to process certain calculations in the function below. Each of these values is specific to a subject ID and doesn't with time. My Question is: How can I can write it in the function so it uses, the first value for each subject ID? As you may notice in the function below, this is what I am currently using:

```
  k10 <- d$k10
  k12 <- d$k12
  k21 <- d$k21
```

Each of these gives a vector of the same value at all time points which is obviously no need for that. I just need one value for each. I think that is one reason why I am getting warnings saying `number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length`

```
#This is the function that I am using:
TwoCompIVbolus <- function(d){

  #set initial values in the compartments
  d$A1[d$TIME==0] <- d$AMT[d$TIME==0]  # drug amount in the central compartment at time zero.
  d$A2[d$TIME==0] <- 0                 # drug amount in the peripheral compartment at time zero.

  k10 <- d$k10
  k12 <- d$k12
  k21 <- d$k21
  k20 <- 0
  E1 <- k10+k12
  E2 <- k21+k20

  #calculate hybrid rate constants
  lambda1 <- 0.5*(k12+k21+k10+sqrt((k12+k21+k10)^2-4*k21*k10))
  lambda2 <- 0.5*(k12+k21+k10-sqrt((k12+k21+k10)^2-4*k21*k10))

  for(i in 2:nrow(d))
  {


    t <- d$TIME[i]-d$TIME[i-1]
    A1last <- d$A1[i-1] 
    A2last <- d$A2[i-1]

    A1term = (((A1last*E2+A2last*k21)-A1last*lambda1)*exp(-t*lambda1)-((A1last*E2+A2last*k21)-A1last*lambda2)*exp(-t*lambda2))/(lambda2-lambda1)
    d$A1[i] = A1term + d$AMT[i] #Amount in the central compartment

    A2term = (((A2last*E1+A1last*k12)-A2last*lambda1)*exp(-t*lambda1)-((A2last*E1+A1last*k12)-A2last*lambda2)*exp(-t*lambda2))/(lambda2-lambda1)
    d$A2[i] = A2term            #Amount in the peripheral compartment

  }
  d
}
#to apply it for each subject
simdf <- ddply(df, .(ID), TwoCompIVbolus)
```

Comment: Could you subset at the function call? Like `TwoCompIVbolus(df[df$TIME==0,])`...

Comment: No I cant. because the function has a for-loop so it has to go from TIME=1 to TIME=2 and from TIME==2 to TIME==3 and so on.

Comment: Why not just use `k10 <- d$k10[1]`?

Comment: ...or maybe `k10 <- d$k10[d$TIME==10]` ?

Comment: @WilliamGearty You are right. Thank you very much! It was easier than I expected. Would you like to put it as an answer so I accept it? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use `k10 <- d$k10[1]`